# implementation of running commentary on any ongoing event

Tags: java, php, javascript, xml, database

I am looking for an implementation of Ongoing of any event in the media in my website.

For example:  want to update the live speech, live session, live football, live cricket live tennis etc.... in my website which is build on PHP & Mysql.

For example, you can refer to this one
http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc_cricket_worldcup2011/engine/current/match/433570.html

Iintially thought of implementing this with the Database, but if there are 1 million people accessing the same commentary then chances of becoming website slow is more, may be due to simultaneous connections are open

I think there are ways of doing with XML features, If any one has ANY IDEAS, please share with me the links or the design, that can defnitely help me in implementing this one.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation this is what came to my mind: [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/)

Hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Observer Design pattern will suit the above situation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

and Ajax HTTP Streaming design pattern will help in achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Overview**
Since you are dealing with live data all the time, there is no need to store it in a database other than for archival purposes. You should have an application scoped buffer that holds the current commentaries for each of the channels (cricket, tennis, football etc.) For displaying it on the page, you should use [ajax polling](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh). Don't go for a push model as it can overload the server.

**How it works**
For the buffer I would recommend a queue data structure. Each line of commentary that is created (from an external system or somebody is typing it in) should be added into the queue with a unique line number. The javascript code in the browser always requests for all new lines since the last displayed line, which should be maintained on the browser in a javascript variable or in a hidden variable. As the queue grows big, you can have one or more threads in your server side that reads the oldest entries from the queue and writes them to a database for archival (if you need the feature).

**Performance Tuning**
The size of the queue, the number of archival threads etc. are tuning parameters that needs to be worked out based on the number of users, the available memory and accepted tolerance for missing lines (some clients can miss out some lines at times when the queue is getting archived too fast). If you know these numbers, you can use [queuing theory](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/34781_basic-queuing-theory) concepts to arrive at the optimum queue size and thread counts.